# polling and javascript in IE 8 working sporadically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, long-polling, polling

I have an asp.net page that reads in a file line by line.  Each line is processed and either added to a db or discarded.  After this is completed I am adding to a counter so I know the number of lines processed, then setting HttpContext.Current.Cache["TotalRecords"] equal to the counter. 
In my ASP page I have a Page Method called GetLatestCount (see below).

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]        
public static int GetLatestCount()
{
    int dt=0;
    try
    {
        dt = (int)HttpContext.Current.Cache["TotalRecs"];                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       console.log();
    }
    return (dt);
}
```

In my Client side script I am polling that PageMethod using Javascript.  Not AJAX or JQUERY.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function Check() 
   {
       // Call the static page method.
       try
       {
            PageMethods.GetLatestCount(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
       }
        catch (ex)
       {
            console.log();
       }
   }

   function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) 
   {
       try
       {
           // Parse the page method's result and the embedded
           // hidden value to integers for comparison.
           var TotalRecs = parseInt(result);
           if (TotalRecs == 999999) 
           {
               lblTotalRecs.innerHTML = "";
           }
           else 
           {

               lblTotalRecs.innerHTML = "Processing Record:  " + TotalRecs;

                setTimeout("Check()", 500);
           }
       }
       catch(ex)
       {

       }
   }

function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) 
{
    alert(error); 
}
```

The file I'm reading in has 4000+ lines so it takes a while to process.  The javascript polling processes twice then doesn't seem to trigger again until half the file is processed (2065 lines read) or up to 30 seconds.  But even that is sporadic.  Sometimes after 3000 lines read or 1000 lines read.  After that it works the way I imagine it should and keeps track of the file's progress.  Any ideas on why it it only gets the last part of the file and not the first?  How do I get this to work in the beginning of the process?

Comment: Just some clarification: PageMethods *are* AJAX. You're not using long polling - long polling means you make a request and your response is delayed until there's something to tell you - your response will happen immediately.

Comment: Try putting some logging (`console.log`) into your javascript `catch`. Also, this seems like it should make the call every half second, and it probably is. I'd bet your problem has nothing to do with what you've posted here. Watch your network tab or Fiddler to see if the AJAX calls are being made.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the bulk of your code in `try/catch`, but not handling the `catch`?

Comment: @JoeEnos, I added the console.log to the catch, and added breakpoints but it never hits.  I have breakpoints on the PageMethods call but it doesn't hit until midway through the file read if ever.

Comment: Since you're not showing the file stuff, nobody can guess. All you're showing is the code which retrieves the result from cache, and from what you're saying, that doesn't appear to be the problem. You'll need to narrow down where your problem is (How are you starting your file job? How are you *writing* to the cache? etc.) From there, I'd bet you'll have either a solution or at least a brand new question.